# Watch resources that are used by exe\dll

Tags: c#, windows, resources, runtime

How can I watch a specific process to know what resources it uses at runtime (such as sounds, pictures, cursors, and registry keys)?

I have to do that *programmatically* using C# (e.g. using the Windows API or any third party library).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the idea of a debugger-help good? (i.e. watching calls to Win API functions such as `LoadCursor`)? The program\dll maybe even encrypted and non-debuggable

Comment: I think this also depends on the environment: native or managed.

Comment: Did you try Process Monitor from SysInternals?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Looks great, but how can I deal with it **programmatically**? This is the useful part

Comment: Huge amount of effort required to re-write procmon. Very broad for an so question.

Comment: have you tried with the visual studio performance/profile analyzer ?

Answer (score 3):

I would stick to performance counters. There are ones for

- Memory
- GDI Handles (Bitmap, Font, ...)
- Handles (File, Registry Key, Event, Mutex, Socket, Process, ...)
- Windows (User Objects)

The exact type cannot be determined by using performance counters but it can give you a hint if you are leaking something. If you want to know which handles you can use handles from SysInternals which will give you a nice per process output which you can parse.

If you want to fix the handle leaks then you need to use a debugger (Windbbg) and use the !handle extension to start tracking all aquire/release call stacks for each handle so you can get latter a statistics which handles have been allocated but not freed yet.

Your question is a little to broad because the exact tactic to nail a resource leakage is dependant on the nature of the leak. EasyHook is a good solution to track all resource aquire/release calls and record them automatically.

If you want to automate a debugger with e.g. C# you can use http://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/ which is bascially a managed wrapper around Windbg which even allows you to self debug your application.

When you just want to learn the principles how to get your hands on scattered data for various resources you should read the code of Process Hacker.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the GDI objects or Win32 handles?
Win32 handles can be obtained using the `NtQuerySystemInformation` WinAPI function. You can find the C# code for handle-related tasks in these ProcessHacker sources: http://sourceforge.net/p/processhacker/code/HEAD/tree/1.x/trunk/ProcessHacker.Native/Windows.cs

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see how to get (in code) used resources given a process id?

Answer (score 1):

[EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) will allow you to intercept Windows API calls. Here's a [simple example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking#_1_2) for all file accesses made by a process. Registry calls [also seem to be supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722555/easyhook-32-bit-application).